# Any $F_\sigma$ set in $\mathbb R$ is a set of discontinuity of some function $f$.

Tags: real-analysis, borel-sets, continuity

Consider the following lemma:

**Lemma**

Let $A\subset \mathbb R$ be an $F_\sigma$ set,then $\exists f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that $D(f)=A$.

Proof: $A=\bigcup\limits_{n\in \mathbb N} A_n$ where $A_n$ are all closed.

Define $f_n:=\large\chi_{A_n}$,characteristic function $A_n$.Define $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n}f_n(x)$ and this function will satisfy the requirement.

This proof was given in stackexchange.But I cannot figure out why $x\in A$ should imply $x\in D(f)$.Can someone help me out of this?The same stack exchange article says that $\exists y$ arbitrarily close to $x\in A$ such that $f_n(x)\neq f_n(y)$ but I do not get it.What if $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset A_n$ for some $n\in \mathbb N$ and for some $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: I don't think this works : every closed set is an $F_{\sigma}$ set, so let us take, say $A = [0,1]$ , with all the $A_n$ then equalling $[0,1]$. Then, $f(x) = 0$ for $x \notin A$ and $f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}=1$ for $x \in A$. This function is basically $1$ on $[0,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere, so its set of discontinuity is $\{0,1\}$, not $A$. Hence the idea and answer above is wrong ; we have to be more creative.

Comment: For a proof of the result in question, see theorem 7.2 in Oxtoby's *Measure and Category*.

Comment: Please tell us where this so-called proof appeared.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629926/function-whose-discontinuity-points-are-a-prefixed-f-sigma-set-in-mathbbr

Comment: Be careful when  you quote other's proofs. You are obviously misquoting the proof.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy does it work?

Comment: What would make this work much easier is if you could express $A$ as a countable union of **pairwise disjoint** closed  sets, but [in general this is not possible](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/6314/13130) (the "pairwise disjoint" part).